# PHP Errors aren't showing

Tags: php, html

I have a simple `HTML script`:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="amount">
    <?php echo $amountError; ?>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And I display errors using this:

```
<?
$amount = $_POST['amount'];

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (empty($_POST['amount'])) {
        $amountError = 'Empty amount';
    } else {
        header("Location: apmoketi.php");
}
?>
```

In the `apmoketi.php` file there is only one line
`echo $amount = $_POST['amount'];`

However, when I'm trying to display data in the `apmoketi.php` page, I don't get the value of the `$amount` variable using `action=""`, but using `action="apmoketi.php"` I can get it but my `PHP` code doesn't checking for any errors, why?

Comment: You're redirecting to another page....the data doesn't come along for the ride.

Comment: How could I display data there? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to `header("Location: apmoketi.php");` makes the browser follow the specified URL as another, completely separate request. This new request doesn't have access to the POST data of the previous one.

Your options:

1. use [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) so *apmoketi.php* has access to the variables of the current script
2. use [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) to preserve data between requests
3. use a query parameter to carry the value over:

   ```
   header('Location: apmoketi.php?amount=' . urlencode($amount));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect to `header("Location: apmoketi.php");`, the variables are no longer in `$_POST[]` so you need to set a session variable before you redirect:

```
$_SESSION['amount'] = $amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

the way i do it is i have a folder called action with subfiles in there lets say the file called file2 in this file all the php action happens.
and in the root of my folder i have another file called file1 and in here theres the html and now how i would do it is

```
<form action="action/file2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="amount">
<?php echo $amountError; ?>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```